# Command not found error in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

When I type the command in the terminal

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf
```

It shows

> sudo: nano /etc/apt/apt.conf :command not found

How do I resolve this?

Comment: most likely you need to install nano. it should be `sudo apt install nano` .... but we have a site specialised in all things ubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/

Comment: Thank you it worked

Answer (score 0):

You will have to install **nano** first.
Run the following command and then try.

1. sudo apt-get install nano
2. sudo nano /etc/apt/apt.conf